# Save array data in variable

Tags: c#, arrays, system

I use function to solve Huffman coding algorithm but the function take string variable as data but i want it to take array when i write `array.ToString()` the function out print some unneeded result because i put array no variable.
this is function code

```
public static void GenerateCode(Node parentNode, string code)
{
    if (parentNode != null)
    {
        GenerateCode(parentNode.leftChild, code + "0");

        if (parentNode.leftChild == null && parentNode.rightChild == null)
        Console.WriteLine(parentNode.data + "{" + code + "}");

        GenerateCode(parentNode.rightChild, code + "1");

    }
}
```

This is my calling for the function in the main:

```
GenerateCode(parentNode1,array.ToString());
```

This is photo with the result:

[image]

I need don't show `System.Int[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `array.ToString()` isn't overridden by the language. Instead, you probably want to use another function, like [`string.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
GenerateCode(parentNode1, string.Concat(array));
```

The result you were getting is because the default implementation of `ToString()` ([`object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), that is) prints out type information.

---

Although if you do have control over the `GenerateCode` method, I would strongly suggest modifying its parameter type to accept an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) or array. Converting to a `string`, unless necessary, will lose some major benefits of strong-typing. I would make that conversion *in* the method, not before it. That will allow you to change the implementation later on without worrying about what parameters you pass.

Furthermore, I'd be tempted to write your values to a `StringBuilder` rather than the console, since that will be way more useful in a majority of real-world applications.

```
public static void GenerateCode(StringBuilder builder, Node parentNode, IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    if (parentNode != null)
    {
        GenerateCode(builder, parentNode.leftChild, Concat(values, 0));

        if (parentNode.leftChild == null && parentNode.rightChild == null)
            builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}{{{1}}}", parentNode.data, string.Concat(values));

        GenerateCode(builder, parentNode.rightChild, Concat(values, 1));
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> Concat(IEnumerable<T> coll, T obj)
{
    foreach (var v in coll)
        yield return v;

    yield return obj;
}
```

Then you can call it, of course, like this.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
GenerateCode(builder, parentNode1, array);
Console.Write(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`string.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
GenerateCode(parentNode1, string.Join("", array));
```

Comment: Not using commas, its a binary representation I believe

Comment: Now it's just my answer :)

Comment: @Mangist Yes, but linking to MSDN is always recommended when you're referencing a particular method in .NET.

Comment: @SpikeX but the result show with the data i put in the array and i don't need that i need only the result of the function

Comment: Sure.  I think the example is enough, the asker can Google the .NET method if they want more info.  99% of the time they will just copy/paste your answer into their code.

Comment: @conn Please edit your post with an example of the output you want, I'm not sure what you mean. The function doesn't have a "result", it returns `void`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is pass in a string representation of your int array.

You can use:

```
GenerateCode(parentNode1, String.Join("", array));
```

Which will concatenate all your ints into a string like 10001010101010111011101